# How to run async method regardless of previous success or failure

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

How, using jQuery deferred objects would I do the following.
Call a webservice.
If it succeeds then do something.
Whether it succeeds or not, do something else.

I tried `$.ajax(...).done(...).fail(...).done(...)`, but the last done never fires if the fail catches a service issue. I also tried `$.ajax(...).then(...,...).done(...)`, but same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/):

```
$.ajax(...).fail(...).always(...);
```

- `.done()` runs on success (when the deferred is resolved)
- `.fail()` runs on error (when the deferred is rejected)
- `.always()` runs, well, always (when the deferred is resolved or rejected)

Comment: Awesome. And a whole 4 minutes later. I love SO. Thanks, Jason P. I didn't even know what to look for.